# How to pass DateTime parameter using Web API attribute routing?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am working on a REST API with ASP.NET Web API 2.
Thing get bad when I try to integrate dates into the game.

Here is the route:

```
[Route("{id:Guid}/{from:DateTime}/{to:DateTime}")]
```

When I do that I can perfectly pass something like

```
.../[id]/2012-01-01/2013-01-01
```

However, when I get to the point where I need the time information it gets quite bad, let's imagine this one:

```
.../[id]/2012-01-01/2013-01-01 1:45:30 PM/2013-01-01 1:45:30 PM
```

It seems like the spaces are going OK but the ":" are blocking. So I though I should use my own format, being yyyyMMddhhmm. This gives the following URL:

```
.../[id]/201301031147/201401031147
```

However, .NET is not expecting this as a DateTime and does not know how to use it. So I used a IHttpRouteConstraint to allow it.
The problem is that it still does not know how to deal with it after I told it it's fine...

So my question is, how do you pass a DateTime to the route?

Comment: Did you try to encode your request url? For instance, if you encode this string **2013-01-01 1:45:30 PM/2013-01-01 1:45:30 PM** you will get this one **2013-01-01%201%3A45%3A30%20PM%2F2013-01-01%201%3A45%3A30%20PM**

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! I actually use RestSharp on the client side and it does that automatically.

Comment: All right. What about making your date string compatible with [The Universal Sortable Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#UniversalSortable). Could you check if that works? Here is a sample date string represented in that format: **2008-04-10 13:30:00Z**

Comment: Thanks again! I tried u, o and s formats described in msdn ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx ) The one you're refeering to is u. No luck this way either sadly... I think there must be a place to tell the framework which format to use or something like that. Or at least a way to take that data and transform it myself into a DateTime

Comment: Couldn't you just use ticks instead? Just a thought... It should be able to convert it then.

Comment: Ok I found a workaround I'm happy with. As the problem seem to be coming from the act that I use the ":" in the date format in the URI itself I moved the dates to the querystring. And it works all fine! I had to remove the /{from:datetime}/{to:datetime} from the route however but... That's all right. Thanks to those who took a bit of their time to look in my issue. Happy New Year!

Comment: One approach to overcome this problem is to convert the datetime object to UTC at the client, and back to datetime from UTC in the webapi.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that : is a URL reserved character in the path.  MVC doesn't expect it to be URL encoded and won't handle it.  However, it is **not reserved in the query string**.

Remove it from your routing specification, but leave them as parameters in your method and the model binder will bind them.  Alternatively, you can also remove them as parameters and access them via the Context query string property or ControllerContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().

So you would have ?fromDate=2012-01-01T1:45:30PM&toDate=2013-01-01T1:45:30PM